# Solve for $x$ in the given determinant.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, determinant

Solve for $x$.

$$
\begin{vmatrix}  
x^2-a^2&x^2-b^2&x^2-c^2\\  
(x-a)^3&(x-b)^3&(x-c)^3\\  
(x+a)^3&(x+b)^3&(x+c)^3\\  
\end{vmatrix}=0.
$$

I could factorise each term, but could not find three factors in a single row or column. Atmost, there were $2$. I cannot think of any manipulations of the rows or columns. Please help.

Comment: @Amzoti I did not dare evaluate it without being able to factorise or some row,column operations, would mess the whole thing up.

Comment: @Amzoti Do you recommend expanding?

Comment: I expanded and arrived to something very simple but I guess that there are smarter manners to do it. What happened to Amzoti's comments ? They are no more here.

Comment: Apply $$C_1'=C_1-C_3,C_2'=C_2-C_3,$$ where $C_i$ is the original $i$th column, $C_i'$ is the modified one

Comment: x=0 ${}{}{}{}{}$

Comment: wolfram alpha says 12 terms with x^3 in 6 and x^5 in others.

Answer (score 1):

I used brute force to solve this.

When we calculate:

$$
\begin{vmatrix}  
x^2-a^2&x^2-b^2&x^2-c^2\\  
(x-a)^3&(x-b)^3&(x-c)^3\\  
(x+a)^3&(x+b)^3&(x+c)^3\\  
\end{vmatrix} = 0
$$

We get:

$$-8 a^3 b^2 x^3+8 a^3 c^2 x^3+8 a^2 b^3 x^3+24 a^2 b x^5-8 a^2 c^3 x^3-24 a^2 c x^5-24 a b^2 x^5+24 a c^2 x^5-8 b^3 c^2 x^3+8 b^2 c^3 x^3+24 b^2 c x^5-24 b c^2 x^5 = 0$$

We see that we can divide by $-8 x^3$ and eliminate a triple root of $x = 0$, which reduces to:

$$(a-b) (a-c) (b-c) \left(-3x^2 + a (b+c)+b c\right) = 0$$

Using the quadratic, we find the other two roots as:

$$x=\pm ~\dfrac{\sqrt{a b+a c+b c}}{\sqrt{3}}$$

Comment: All that work deserves some credit! Thanks for taking this to the endzone for a touchdown!

Comment: Yeah. I certainly oversimplified matters in my poor "solution".